# "These samplers cannot be used in parallelized code"

Tags: r, rcpp

I was reading the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgen/vignettes/using-samplers.html) for the [rgen](https://github.com/cran/rgen) package which provides headers for sampling from some common distributions. In the first paragraph, it says that:

> Please note, these samplers, just like the ones in armadillo cannot be used in parallelized code as the underlying generation routines rely upon R calls that are single-threaded.

This was news to me, and I've been using RcppArmadillo for quite some time now. I was wondering if someone could elaborate on this point (or provide references to where I can read about the issue). I'm especially interested in learning what "cannot be used" means here; will results be wrong, or will it just not parallelize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These functions use R's random number generator, which must not be used in parallelized code, since that leads to undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can lead to virtually anything. From my point of view you are lucky if the program crashes, since this clearly tells you that something is going wrong.

The [HPC task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) lists some RNGs that are suitable for parallel computation. But you cannot use them easily with the distributions provided by rgen or [RcppDist](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppDist). Instead, one could do the following:

- Copy function for multivariate normal distribution from `rgen` an adjust it's signature such that it takes a `std::function<double()>` as source for `N(0, 1)` distributed random numbers.
- Use a fast RNG instead of R's RNG.
- Use the same fast RNG in parallel mode.

In code as a quick hack:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(dqrng)]]
#include <xoshiro.h>
#include <dqrng_distribution.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <omp.h>

inline arma::mat rmvnorm(unsigned int n, const arma::vec& mu, const arma::mat& S,
                         std::function<double()> rnorm = norm_rand){
  unsigned int ncols = S.n_cols;
  arma::mat Y(n, ncols);
  Y.imbue( rnorm ) ;
  return arma::repmat(mu, 1, n).t() + Y * arma::chol(S);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat defaultRNG(unsigned int n, const arma::vec& mu, const arma::mat& S) {
  return rmvnorm(n, mu, S);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat serial(unsigned int n, const arma::vec& mu, const arma::mat& S) {
  dqrng::normal_distribution dist(0.0, 1.0);
  dqrng::xoshiro256plus rng(42);
  return rmvnorm(n, mu, S, [&](){return dist(rng);});
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<arma::mat> parallel(unsigned int n, const arma::vec& mu, const arma::mat& S, unsigned int ncores = 1) {
  dqrng::normal_distribution dist(0.0, 1.0);
  dqrng::xoshiro256plus rng(42);
  std::vector<arma::mat> res(ncores);

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(ncores)
  {
    dqrng::xoshiro256plus lrng(rng);      // make thread local copy of rng 
    lrng.jump(omp_get_thread_num() + 1);  // advance rng by 1 ... ncores jumps 
    res[omp_get_thread_num()] = rmvnorm(n, mu, S, [&](){return dist(lrng);});
  }
  return res;
}


/*** R
set.seed(42)
N <- 1000000
M <- 100
mu <- rnorm(M)
S <- matrix(rnorm(M*M), M, M)
S <- S %*% t(S)
system.time(defaultRNG(N, mu, S))
system.time(serial(N, mu, S))
system.time(parallel(N/2, mu, S, 2))
*/
```

Result:

```
> system.time(defaultRNG(N, mu, S))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.984   1.380   6.881 

> system.time(serial(N, mu, S))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.008   1.448   3.971 

> system.time(parallel(N/2, mu, S, 2))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.824   2.096   3.080
```

Here the real performance improvement comes from using a faster RNG, which is understandable since the focus here lies on many random numbers and not so much on matrix operations. If I shift more towards matrix operations by using `N <- 100000` and `M <- 1000` I get:

```
> system.time(defaultRNG(N, mu, S))
   user  system elapsed 
 16.740   1.768   9.725 

> system.time(serial(N, mu, S))
   user  system elapsed 
 13.792   1.864   6.792 

> system.time(parallel(N/2, mu, S, 2))
   user  system elapsed 
 14.112   3.900   5.859
```

Here we clearly see that in **all** cases user time is larger than elapsed time. The reason for this is the parallel BLAS implementation I am using (OpenBLAS). So there are quite a few factors to consider before deciding on a method.

Comment: So I would guess that many packages providing fast sampling routines (`rgen` included) make use of Rcpp in one way or another---none of these will be suitable for parallel implementations? If we flip the question around: if I want to sample say multivariate normal numbers in parallel using a speedy C++ implementation, what is the suggested way to go about this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ralf. I'll leave the question open for a little while longer in case anyone else wants to chip in, then I will accept yours.

Comment: A follow-up question: is it possible to remove the `rng(42)` line in `parallel()`, do `dqset.seed(42)` in R and then do multiple calls (say in a loop) to `parallel`, with other C++ calls generating random numbers in between?

Comment: @hejseb Not at the moment. Currently it is not possible to get hold of the global RNG used by `dqset.seed` to derive thread local versions. But you can of course provide your own seed.

Comment: Do you mean like adding `int seed` as an argument to `parallel()`, modifying the `rng` line into `dqrng::xoshiro256plus rng(seed);` and then do e.g. `parallel(N/2, mu, S, 2, i)` where `i` is the loop iterator? My problem is that I have a loop in R with blocks implemented in C++, one of which consists of sampling independently from a bunch of multivariate normal distributions. Because of their independence, I do them in parallel, but I obviously want to do that correctly.

Comment: @hejseb You are talking about parallelism in R and not C++? That is a different story, because in that case you have multiple R processes, each with their own RNG. So the only issue is how to make the different random streams independent and reproducible. The `parallel` vignette talks about that. And the `doRNG` package is useful when using `foreach`.

Comment: Alright, I think I get the difference now. If I do `foreach` or `parSapply` using a function `foo` implemented in C++ I'm fine if I set the rng stream wisely, but if I would do the parallel call in C++ I'd need to be careful. My plan was to go C++ all the way, so even though I'm safe at the moment your answer is very valuable for that transition.